# Java modify vector items

Tags: java

I am using a vector to add my JList items to like below

```
public void addToList() {
    Icon pingImage = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/icnNew.png"));
    JLabel pingLabel = new JLabel("ID #231231", pingImage, JLabel.LEFT);
    JPanel pingPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    pingPanel.add(pingLabel);
    v.add(pingPanel);

    menuList.setListData(v);
}
```

My Requirement is to update items within the vector depending on their ID. For example : On the above, i would like to change the ImageIcon for the ID #231231.

How could this be done?

Comment: Vector is long replaced by ArrayList. It is much efficient to use.

Comment: Go through the elements in your vector, find the one you want and change it. Or use a map.

Comment: @Sotirios but how can i find the right item in my vector? Which has the above ID?

Comment: Does it have to be a Vector? Why not use a HashMap with the id as the key?

Comment: @Alosyius Get each panel, get its label, check the text.

Comment: @Alosyius You can get the components of a panel (the only one of which should be the label) and you can get the text of a label, but it's a much better idea to use a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments to your question, a Vector is the wrong data structure. Doing updates based on an identifier is asking for a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). I would recommend against iterating through a list, looking for matching labels, since its an O(n) instead of O(log n) operation.